# Какие события поддерживает $element в директивах Angular

Tags: angularjs, события, angular-directive

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module("app")
    .directive('myDirective', [getmyDirective]);

  function getmyDirective() {
    try {
      var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        template: '<dir class="myDirective" ></dir>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: false,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
          $scope.$watch(function() {
              return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            },
            function(newValue, oldValue) {
              SetSize();
            }
          );

          function SetSize() {
            $scope.width = $element.width();
          }
        },
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
          return {
            pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {},
            post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                scope.SetSize();
              }, 1000);

            }
          }
        },
      }
      return directiveDefinitionObject;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
})();
```

Мне необходимо получить ширину блока, занимаемого директивой $scope.width.
В свойствах блока ширина равна 100% родительского блока.

Изначально, после загрузки сайта директива на странице отсутствует. После загрузки она имеет свойство display:hidden (находится под спойлером).

Как видно из кода, измерение ширины производится как можно позже, через 1 сек после того как срабатывает compile postlink. Тем не менее, результат измерения $scope.width=100.

При изменении размеров окна, после того как директива стала видимой,

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return document.documentElement.clientWidth; })
```

измерение $scope.width дает реальный результат.

**Вопрос:** Какие существуют события $element, на которые можно было бы повесить $watch, чтобы отследить реальную ширину директивы? Где это можно прочитать?
Решение вешать события на $('.myDirective') не подходят, директива используется многократно, размеры элементов разные.

Передавать внешний параметр - тоже не подходит. Ширину элемента должна определить сама директива.

Пример:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.isOpen = false;
});
app.directive('myDirective', [ getmyDirective]); 
function getmyDirective(){
 var directiveDefinitionObject = {
 template: '<dir class="myDirective" ><dir ng-style="dstyle[size]">window1 {{width}}</dir><dir ng-style="dstyle[size]">window2 {{size}}</dir></dir>',
 replace: true,
 transclude:false,
 restrict: 'AE',
 scope: false,
 controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs ) {
  $scope.$watch(function() { return document.documentElement.clientWidth; },
   function(newValue, oldValue) {
    SetSize();
   }
  );
  $scope.SetSize = SetSize;
  $scope.dstyle = [
    { 'width': '25%' , 'float': 'left'},
    { 'width': '100%' }
   ];
  function SetSize(){
   $scope.width = 
  // 150;
   $element.width() ; 
   $scope.size= ($scope.width > 200 )? 0: 1;
  }
 },
 compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
  return {
   pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {},
   post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     scope.SetSize();
    },1000);
  
   }
  }
 },
 }
 return directiveDefinitionObject;
}
```

```css
.container { width: 100vw}
 .inside {width: 100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

  <button ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen" >Open</button>
  <div ng-if="isOpen"  class="container">
   <div data-my-directive  class="inside"></div>
  </div>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а зачем тело директивы в `try...catch`?

Comment: `$element` - это jqLite объект, события у него такие же как и у jQuery Объекта, каким боком тут `$watch` который находится в `$scope`?

Comment: try...catch - на всякий случай, это не принципиально. Проект пока в разработке и так удобнее отлавливать ошибки.

Comment: без примера абсолютно непонятно что делает данная директива и в чем заключается проблема, которую непонятно как пытаешься решить

Comment: надо запустить функцию setSize в тот момент, когда элемент будет иметь конкретную ширину. Вызов в $watch $element.width() вызывает ошибку, т.к. в определенный моменты $element не существует

Comment: Так я на 90% привел исходный текст директивы. Далее она сравнивает $scope.width с заданным значением и в зависимости от результата устанавливает стили элемента

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42962/discussion-between-grundy-and-dolalex).

Answer (score 1):

Из беседы с @Grundy пришло решение:
Проблема состояла в том, что директива, скрытая посредством jQuery не имела собственной ширины. Поэтому "оживление" директивы следовало накладывать не на ее саму, а на элемент jQuery.
В данном случае использовался аккордеон. На панель аккордеона была наложена функция на событие ng-click, вызывающее apply (как именно вызывается apply описывать не буду, т.к. я это делаю не лучшим способом) с небольшой (100ms) временной задержкой, чтобы jQuery успел открыть элемент и задать ему ширину.